# How to verify if a recovery software can actually recover a file deleted from a recycle bin?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

For a Windows 10 system,
I've been trying to test if [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) (a data recovery software) is capable of restoring a file that is deleted from the Recycle Bin.

To do the test, I deleted an image titled "TEST.png" out of the Recycle Bin and then immediately used the software to do a deep hours-long scan for files to recover.
However, after the scan, the same test file could not be found.

Is there a better way to do this kind of verification?

*(image used)*
[image: TEST image]

Comment: A better way would be to take the disk offline immediately after the file is deleted, since as long as the system is running there would be data read/write actions (temp files and stuff).   If you are practising data recovery or doing some research, just create a smaller partition for that, it'll save you time.

Comment: also [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-file-recovery/9n26s50ln705?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=nOD%2frLJHOac&ranSiteID=nOD_rLJHOac-G276lOpePwFmOTC_tui6pA&epi=nOD_rLJHOac-G276lOpePwFmOTC_tui6pA&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=$ir__yvlnkd1jsckft13ekk0sohzw0f2xivfxev1cwdc200$$7593$$1243925$$nOD_rLJHOac-G276lOpePwFmOTC_tui6pA$$$&irclickid=_yvlnkd1jsckft13ekk0sohzw0f2xivfxev1cwdc200&SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) is a new toy from Microsoft you might want to play with.